# What's the error with this xor

Tags: c++, xor

Why, when using this xor in C++,

```
int main() {
    bitset<4> a=1100, b=0110,c;
    c = a ^ b;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

is the result 0100?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those constants aren't in binary, that's why.  1100 decimal is `10001001100` binary. 0110 *octal* is `1001000` binary.  (Why octal for the second one?  Because a constant that starts with a leading zero and consists only of digits 0..7 is octal in C++.)

When you truncate both to 4 bits, you get `1100` binary XORed with `1000` binary, which gives `0100` binary.

Try this instead (assuming your compiler supports the nonstandard prefix `0b` for binary literals):

```
int main() {
    bitset<4> a=0b1100, b=0b0110,c;
    c = a ^ b;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternately, specify your constants in hexadecimal:

```
int main() {
    bitset<4> a=0xC, b=0x6,c;
    c = a ^ b;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

or as string constants: (C++11)

```
int main() {
    bitset<4> a( "1100" ), b( "0110" ),c;
    c = a ^ b;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Binary literals (`0b...`) aren't part of standard C++ (will be in C++14 though). Some compilers implement them as an extension.

Comment: @interjay : Fair enough... I'll mention that above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that literals 1100 and 0110 are not binary literals. The first one is decimal literal 1100 and the second one is octal literal 0110 that in decimal is equivalent to 24. You should use string literals to achive the desired result. For example consider results of the following code snipet

```
    std::bitset<4> a = 1100, b = 0110, c;
    c = a ^ b;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;

    std::bitset<4> a1( "1100" ), b1( "0110" ), c1;
    c1 = a1 ^ b1;
    std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1 = " << b1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c1 = " << c1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: My mistake. I did not multiply 8 by 8 but myltiply 8 by 2.:)